# How to change header include guards in Rcpp interfaces?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am lately trying to learn the (brilliant) Rcpp library. When I want to export some of my C++ code, afaik it is suggested to use sth like:

```
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
// [[Rcpp::export(name=".mrwr_cpp")]]
Eigen::VectorXd mrwr_(const Eigen::VectorXd& p0,
                      const Eigen::MatrixXd& W,
                      const double r)
{
  // impl
}
```

In this example `// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]` would create a header file with the name of my R package (lets say the package is called `diffusr`). The content of the exported header (`diffusr.h`) would look like this:

```
// This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#ifndef __diffusr_h__
#define __diffusr_h__

#include "diffusr_RcppExports.h"

#endif // __diffusr_h__
```

Is there a way to change the header include guard autamatically? Two leading "_" might lead to undefined behaviour, if I am correct, and is reserved for the standard library ([What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797))

Best, 
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly:

- "You don't", as that is done in the code generators within Rcpp, so you would have to change Rcpp
- Check the master branch on GitHub corresponding to the next release (in a week or two) as [this was recently changed](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/528)

Comment: Yes. While this had not bitten us in all these years, it is a change for the better.